# Regarding some properties of positive measure set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be of positive measure. Can we find a positive measure compact set $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the set
$$\lbrace x|x-y\in E, \forall y\in K\rbrace$$
is of positive measure?

Comment: Take $y=0.$ Or am I misreading your question?

Comment: In other words, given a positive measure set $E$, you want positive measure sets $K$ and $X$ such that $X-K\subseteq E$. (And you also want $K$ to be compact, but that's no problem.) I don't think you can do that if $n=1$ and $E$ is the set of all irrational numbers.

Comment: Yes your simplification is correct. By steinhaus theorem we can't do that. Isn't it?@bof

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind, the Steinhaus theorem. I was trying to remember the name of that theorem. The sum (difference) of two positive measure sets contains an interval.